# Copy PDFs from Directory and Include Sub Directories

Tags: powershell

I [had help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69269411/45375) creating a PowerShell Script to copy files from 1 directory into more structured directories.  Is there a way I can adjust the script so that it looks for PDF files in any Sub Folders too?   Any help would be appreciated!   Thank you!

```
# Input and output (root) directory paths.
$inPath = 'Z:\PDF Archive\2010\TEST'
$outPathRoot = 'Z:\PDF Archive'

# The max. number of digits in the input file names.
$maxDigits = 7

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $inPath -Filter *.pdf | ForEach-Object {

  # Left-pad the number string that constitutes the base file name
  # with zeros to ensure a length of 7.  
  $paddedNum = $_.BaseName.PadLeft($maxDigits, '0')

  # Construct the name of the subdirectories to copy the files to,
  # replacing the digits after the leading 2 and 3 digits first with "0" and "9",
  # respectively, joining the resulting strings with "-"
  $subDirs = 
    foreach ($leadingDigits in $paddedNum.Substring(0, 2), $paddedNum.Substring(0, 3)) {
      ($leadingDigits + '0' * ($maxDigits - $leadingDigits.Length)),
      ($leadingDigits + '9' * ($maxDigits - $leadingDigits.Length)) -join '-'
    }

  # Create the output subdirectories, if necessary.
  # -Force both creates parent directories on demand and 
  # quietly returns an existing directory, if present.
  $targetDir = New-Item -Type Directory -Force ($outPathRoot + '\' + ($subDirs -join '\'))

  # Copy the PDF file at hand to the target subdirectory.
  $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetDir.FullName
```

Comment: To make your [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) call search the target directory's entire directory _subtree_, you must add the `-Recurse` switch. Is that all you're looking for?

Comment: I believe Recurse did the trick!
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath  $inPath -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

Comment: I actually moved it here and I think it works better            

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath  $inPath -Filter *.pdf | ForEach-Object {

Comment: Glad to hear it, but note that order in which named arguments are passed (which includes switches such as `-Recurse`) generally makes no difference in PowerShell.